# Using select() in R giving "Error inputs must resolve to integer column positions"

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a script which gradually adds a number of columns to an existing data frame (*df1*) and then from this will then take a subset of these columns and output it as *df2*, whilst renaming the columns at the same time.

I've previously used the `select()` function in dplyr to do this and it has actually worked previously on similar datasets, so I'm a bit stumped as to why it's not working all of a sudden now. I've seen a few other threads about using `select()` but none of them really helped with my question.

Here is the column list and first line of the data I am using:

```
gene_id variant_id tss_distance ma_samples ma_count maf pval_nominal slope slope_se rsid chr pos ref_allele alt gene_id_new gene_name info
ENSG00000227232.4 1_13417_C_CGAGA_b37       -16136         50       50 0.07225430   0.00908288  0.3556660 0.1354910 rs777038595   1 13417          C CGAGA ENSG00000227232    WASH7P    1
```

Here is the code for my selection:

```
parsed_columns = select(df1, chr = "chr",
                    pos = "pos",
                    ref = "ref_allele",
                    alt = "alt",
                    reffrq = "maf",
                    info = "info",
                    rs = "rsid",
                    pval = "pval_nominal",
                    effalt = "slope",
                    gene = "gene_name")
```

And from this I get an error saying that all of the names in the quotations `do not resolve to integer positions`.

I initially thought I might just have the names on the wrong side of the function (so, for example, it should be `rsid = "rs"`) but then you have columns where it is the same on both sides (e.g. `pos = "pos"`) and supposedly that isn't present either. So I'm a bit stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With the select function the new column name should go in quotes on the left hand side of the equal symbol like this `"rs" = rsid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dplyr, do you need to have your column names in quotations. Simply adding the column name of the referenced data frame should suffice.

More generically,

```
df2 = select(df1,
             col1name = col1
             col2name = col2
             ...
             )
```

Provided that the col1, col2, etc. are valid column names in df1.

Give this a try for your R code

```
parsed_columns = select(df1, chr = chr,
                    pos = pos,
                    ref = ref_allele,
                    alt = alt,
                    reffrq = maf,
                    info = info,
                    rs = rsid,
                    pval = pval_nominal,
                    effalt = slope,
                    gene = gene_name)
```